# How to extract a JSON Array entry in C# for Infopath

Tags: c#, json

I am new to programming.
Wanted to Create a C# Infopath Button which will send SMS when Clicked.
Everything went well except the response from server.
I was able to display this response,
but I want to display Some Part of WEb response.
Here is My Code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.InfoPath;
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
//using System.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;



namespace SMS_Form_Fields
{
    public partial class FormCode
    {
        // Member variables are not supported in browser-enabled forms.
        // Instead, write and read these values from the FormState
        // dictionary using code such as the following:
        //
        // private object _memberVariable
        // {
        //     get
        //     {
        //         return FormState["_memberVariable"];
        //     }
        //     set
        //     {
        //         FormState["_memberVariable"] = value;
        //     }
        // }

        // NOTE: The following procedure is required by Microsoft InfoPath.
        // It can be modified using Microsoft InfoPath.
        public void InternalStartup()
        {
            EventManager.FormEvents.Submit += new SubmitEventHandler(FormEvents_Submit);

        }

        public void FormEvents_Submit(object sender, SubmitEventArgs e)
        {

            var UriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://smsgateway.me/api/v3/messages/send/");
            var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
            parameters["email"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:email", NamespaceManager).Value;
            parameters["password"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:password", NamespaceManager).Value;
            parameters["device"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:device", NamespaceManager).Value; ;
            parameters["number"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:MobileNumber", NamespaceManager).Value;
            parameters["message"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:SMS_TO_BE_SENT", NamespaceManager).Value; ;
            UriBuilder.Query = parameters.ToString();
            //UriBuilder.Fragment = "some_fragment";

            Uri finalUrl = UriBuilder.Uri;
            var request = WebRequest.Create(finalUrl);

            // Get the response.
            WebResponse result = request.GetResponse();


             // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = result.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();





dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
var result1 = stuff.result;
var success1 = result1.success;


string value = Convert.ToString(success1);



            // Display the content.

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(value);


        }
            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            result.Close();


        }
    }
```

Here is JSON Example for success

```
{
"success": true,
"result": {
"success": [
{
"id": "308",
"device_id": "4",
"message": "hello world!",
"status": "pending",
"send_at": "1414624856",
"queued_at": "0",
"sent_at": "0",
"delivered_at": "0",
"expires_at": "1414634856",
"canceled_at": "0",
"failed_at": "0",
"received_at": "0",
"error": "None",
"created_at": "1414624856",
"contact": {
"id": "14",
"name": "Phyllis Turner",
"number": "+447791064713"
}
}
],
"fails": [
]
}
}
```

Here is JSON Example for failure

```
{
"success": true,
"result": {
"success": [
],
"fails": [
"number": "+44771232343"
"message": "hello world!",
"device": 1
"errors": {
"device": ["The selected device is invalid"],
}
]
}
}
```

All I want to do is if it is succeeds I Should be able to display any part of JSON, for example ID, Device Id or Message
and if it is a failure then also I should be able to display any part of JSON for example Device, number or errors.

Updated Failure Response after SteveJ pointed:

```
   {
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "success": [],
        "fails": [
            {
                "email": "abc@xyz.com",
                "password": "anypassword",
                "device": 1,
                "number": "+44771232343",
                "message": "hello world!",
                "errors": {
                    "device": [
                        "The selected device is invalid"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: so the question can be simplified to: how to extract a JSON entry in C#? i am pretty sure the answer to that is on SO and other parts of the web already.

Comment: Thanks  hoijui for advice. Any reference where I can find the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which resolved My Problem. Credit goes to SteveJ.

```
using Microsoft.Office.InfoPath;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using mshtml;
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace sms_form1
    {
    public class Contact
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string number { get; set; }
    }

    public class Success
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string device_id { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string send_at { get; set; }
        public string queued_at { get; set; }
        public string sent_at { get; set; }
        public string delivered_at { get; set; }
        public string expires_at { get; set; }
        public string canceled_at { get; set; }
        public string failed_at { get; set; }
        public string received_at { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }
        public string created_at { get; set; }
        public Contact contact { get; set; }
    }

    public class Errors
    {
        public List<String> device { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fail
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string device { get; set; }
        public string number { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public Errors errors { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public List<Success> success { get; set; }
        public List<Fail> fails { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class FormCode
    {
        public void InternalStartup()
        {
            EventManager.FormEvents.Submit += new SubmitEventHandler(FormEvents_Submit);
        }

        public void FormEvents_Submit(object sender, SubmitEventArgs e)
        {

            var UriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://smsgateway.me/api/v3/messages/send/");
            var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
            parameters["email"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:email", NamespaceManager).Value;
            parameters["password"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:password", NamespaceManager).Value;
            parameters["device"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:device", NamespaceManager).Value; ;
            parameters["number"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:MobileNumber", NamespaceManager).Value;
            parameters["message"] = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:SMS_TO_BE_SENT", NamespaceManager).Value; ;
            UriBuilder.Query = parameters.ToString();
            //UriBuilder.Fragment = "some_fragment";

            Uri finalUrl = UriBuilder.Uri;
            var request = WebRequest.Create(finalUrl);

            // Get the response.
            WebResponse result = request.GetResponse();





            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = result.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();


            var successRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseFromServer);

           var isSuccess = successRoot.result.success != null && successRoot.result.success.Count > 0;
          var isFail = successRoot.result.fails != null && successRoot.result.fails.Count > 0;

          if (isSuccess)
          {
              var id = successRoot.result.success.First().id;
              var message = successRoot.result.success.First().message;
             // Display the content.

             string value = Convert.ToString(id);
             string value1 = Convert.ToString(message);
              System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("SMS "+value+" "+value1+" Sent SuccessFully" );
                     }
          else
          {
              //var messagefail = successRoot.result.fails.First().device;
              //string value = Convert.ToString(messagefail);

              System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("SMS Could Not Be Sent. Check Device");
                     }

           // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            result.Close();


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: The fail response that you give doesn't validate. Paste it into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and you will see it fails validation. Perhaps this is a copy/paste error - but you will need to get that straightened out. That aside, here are the steps.

1. Combine Success and Fail into one Json object (see my example below)
2. Paste your Json into a website such as http://json2csharp.com/. This will give you the classes that model your Json Object (seem my second example below)
3. Uses NewtonSoft's method, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) to convert your json string into an instance of the RootObject class (rename that class if you like)
4. User the newly created class like any other, no longer needing to be aware that it came from a web service.

**Example 1: Modified Json**

```
    {
    "success": true,
    "result": 
    {
        "success": 
        [
            {
                "id": "308",
                "device_id": "4",
                "message": "hello world!",
                "status": "pending",
                "send_at": "1414624856",
                "queued_at": "0",
                "sent_at": "0",
                "delivered_at": "0",
                "expires_at": "1414634856",
                "canceled_at": "0",
                "failed_at": "0",
                "received_at": "0",
                "error": "None",
                "created_at": "1414624856",
                "contact": 
                {
                    "id": "14",
                    "name": "Phyllis Turner",
                    "number": "+447791064713"
                }
            }
        ],
        "fails": 
        [
            {
                "number": "+44771232343",
                "message": "hello world!",
                "device": 1,
                "errors": 
                {
                    "device": ["The selected device is invalid"]
                }
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

**Example 2 : List of Classes Needed**

```
public class Contact
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}

public class Success
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string device_id { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string send_at { get; set; }
    public string queued_at { get; set; }
    public string sent_at { get; set; }
    public string delivered_at { get; set; }
    public string expires_at { get; set; }
    public string canceled_at { get; set; }
    public string failed_at { get; set; }
    public string received_at { get; set; }
    public string error { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public Contact contact { get; set; }
}

public class Errors
{
    public List<string> device { get; set; }
}

public class Fail
{
    public string number { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public int device { get; set; }
    public Errors errors { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Success> success { get; set; }
    public List<Fail> fails { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var successJson = "{\"success\": true,\"result\": {\"success\": [{\"id\": \"308\",\"device_id\": \"4\"," +
                          "\"message\": \"hello world!\",\"status\": \"pending\",\"send_at\": \"1414624856\", \"queued_at\": \"0\", " +
                          "\"sent_at\": \"0\", \"delivered_at\": \"0\", \"expires_at\": \"1414634856\", \"canceled_at\": \"0\"," +
                          "\"failed_at\": \"0\", \"received_at\": \"0\", \"error\": \"None\", \"created_at\": \"1414624856\"," +
                          "\"contact\": {\"id\": \"14\", \"name\": \"Phyllis Turner\", \"number\": \"+447791064713\"} " +
                          "}],\"fails\": []}}";

        var successRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(successJson);

        var isSuccess = successRoot.result.success != null && successRoot.result.success.Count > 0;
        var isFail = successRoot.result.fails != null && successRoot.result.fails.Count > 0;
        var message = successRoot.result.success.First().message;

    }
```

Comment: Bundle of Thanks SteveJ. Success and failure are two different responses from HTTP Post Web Server, Is it possible to combine them in a single JSON.?

Comment: SteveJ how can I use the Class List in my code? If you do not mind, can you provide me with the complete code?

Comment: Fail Response straightened out

Comment: @AshBukhari Sorry, I could have been more clear. The class you want to use is RootObject. I'll code something up and edit my post.

Comment: @AshBukhari The way I read your the example is that the web request will always return the same object. If success, the success array will be filled out. If failure, the failure array will be filled out. Thus, knowing whether the result is failed or success should be a matter of checking the success or fail objects in the "root.result" object. I included a check for success in my usage example.

Comment: SteveJ Thanks again. If you can guide me step by step as I am new to Programming. If you can provide me the code from  start of the code for example                                            using Microsoft.Office.InfoPath;
using System;
                              to the End

Comment: @AshBukhari Sorry, I don't have any infopath experience. In general, though, suppose you had a text field (MyTextField), you could use the "successRoot" class I show below to define its value. MyTextField.text = successRoot.result.success.First().message; I don't think that I'm going to get you much further than this.

Comment: Thanks for Help so far.You are awesome, great . By Help of your code I am able to handle success response. If you can help me how to handle failure response?

Comment: Thanks for Help so far.You are awesome, great . By Help of your code I am able to handle success response and failure response manually (means to say creating another failure response like "var messagefail = successRoot.result.fails.First().message;". If you can just help me to cross the last hurdle: if it is success response, than VS2012 at runtime shows error at failure response and if it is failure response VS2012 at runtime shows error at success response saying Sequence contains no elements

Comment: Can you tell me specifically what line of code causes the error?

Comment: Thanks for Help. I Am able to get the required code by your Help.